# Node JS loading js & css file in an ejs file

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, express, ejs

My folder is like so :
server.js
app
--routes.js
views
--ace-builds-master
   --\src-noconflict
      --ace.js
--index.ejs

So in 'views' is my ace editor stuff and my index.ejs file.
I want to call ace.js in my index.ejs file. Do I need to create an app.get in my express routes like below?

```
app.get('/ace', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile('\ace-builds-master\src-noconflict\ace.js');
});
```

And in my ejs file do I write it like so:

```
<script src="/ace" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"> </script>
```

I receive a "GET http://localhost:8080/ace" when loading in browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ejs renders the view file,view can access your static folder .You can make your ace folder as static . It will be loaded when view load

```
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// Load static files
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'ace')));
```

Comment: its saying it cannot find path

Comment: you can not call like http://localhost:8080/ace through url ,  you can do <script src="/ace" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"> </script>
@AndrewONeill

Comment: can you clearly specify your folder structure @AndrewONeill

Comment: you can like my answer and mark it answered, so that I get motivated to help others @AndrewONeill

Answer (score 0):

just use

```
<script src="../ace" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"> </script>
```

instead of

```
<script src="/ace" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"> </script>
```

because when server loads ejs it makes a virtual folder inside the public folder 
so you just need to go one step back.

Comment: This is not an full answer